# Android - Validating EditText fields after setting them programmatically

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

On a Fragment for user logging, I have two `EditText` widgets - one for email and the other for password. When the user has saved its credentials via `SharedPreferences`, then these are obtained to fill the input fields programmatically via `setText()` like this:

```
// obtain the credentials
val email : String? = loginFragmentViewModel.retrieveEmailFromSharedPreferences()
val password: String ? = loginFragmentViewModel.retrivePasswordFromSharedPreferences()

email?.let { emailString->
        password?.let{ pw ->

               // fill the EditText inputs programmatically
               binding.apply{
                    loginEmail.setText(emailString)
                    loginPassword.setText(pw)
               }

               // validate the input data
               loginFragmentViewModel.loginDataChanged(
                        binding.loginEmail.text.toString(),
                        binding.loginPassword.text.toString()
               )
        }
}
```

The `loginDataChanged()` method is implemented on the ViewModel side. It validates the given inputs (here: email & password). Here the relevant parts:

```
private val _loginState =  MutableLiveData<LoginFormState>()
val loginFormState : LiveData<LoginFormState> = _loginState

fun loginDataChanged(email: String, password: String){
        if(!isEmailValid(email)){
            _loginState.value = LoginFormState(emailError = R.string.invalid_email)
        }
        else if(!isPasswordValid(password)){
            _loginState.value = LoginFormState(passwordError = R.string.invalid_password)
        }
        else{
            _loginState.value = LoginFormState(isDataValid = true)
        }
}
```

As you can see, based on the validation result, we update the LiveData variable which leads us back to the `LoginFragment` side:

```
// listen for type errors made by the user during the login
loginFormState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { loginFormState ->
       ...
       ...
       // notify the user that the given email is wrong
       loginFormState.emailError?.let{
               binding.loginEmail.error = getString(it)
       }

       // notify the user that the given password is wrong
       loginFormState.passwordError?.let{
               binding.loginPassword.error = getString(it)
       }
})
```

As you can see, when there is any error with an input, I let the user know about via the `error` property of EditText widget. They show an exclamation mark, notifying the user that the input is not correct.

What my problem is:
But that does not work when the inputs are set programmatically like you have seen above. After setting them like this, you can still see the exclamation mark on the right side of the EditText widgets **ALTHOUGH** the given email and password are correct. When the correct email and password are obtained from `SharedPreferences` and the `EditText` fields are filled, then it still looks like as they are wrong. But they are not.

So, how can I solve this problem?

Note: I obtain the SharedPreferences so that the user does not have to re-type them.

Comment: So `loginDataChanged()` is being called but the Observer assigned to `loginFormState` is not being called?

Comment: Please make sure the observer is not called before the loginDataChanged(). I have sometimes observed the Love data observer is being executed without the actual call to VM method. You can check this by adding logs